# In UWP, how to skip tab key navigation for an UserControl and all of its child element?

Tags: xaml, uwp, focus, windows-10-universal, uwp-navigation

In UWP, I want to handle and skip the tab key navigation for particular set of controls dynamically.

For e.g., I've two user controls (Both have lot of children which will be added dynamically) in my main page and want to skip tab key navigation for one usercontrol dynamically on specific scenario for a moment.

So I've tried to set "**IsTabStop**" as false to that UserControl. But which is not effective on its child controls. Still tab key focus moved inside the children of that UserControl.

Note: If I set "IsEnabled" as false, then its working. But I don't want to use because it affects Visual appearance.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `IsTabStop` property in `StackPanel` class. The `IsTabStop` property is defined in [Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.istabstop?view=winrt-19041#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Control_IsTabStop) class, and the `StackPanel` class is not inherited from `Control` class, either directly or indirectly. You can not use `IsTabStop` property to set a `StackPanel` instance.

Therefore, if you want to skip tab key navigation for one stackpanel, you need to set the `IsTabStop` property to `False` in each control in the stackpanel.

**Update:**

By testing, the child elements in a `UserControl` can not inherit the value of `IsTabStop` property. Therefore, you cannot skip tab key navigation for all the child elements in a `UserControl` by setting the `IsTabStop` property to False.

You could use a method defind in your `UserControl` class to set `IsTabStop` to false for every item in your `UserControl`.

For example:

MyUserControl.cs

```
public void SetIsTabStop(bool flag)
{
    var result = VisualTreeFindAll<Control>(this);
    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        item.IsTabStop=flag;
    }
}
private IList<T> VisualTreeFindAll<T>(DependencyObject element)
            where T : DependencyObject
{
    List<T> retValues = new List<T>();
    var childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element);
    for (var i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i);
        var type = child as T;
        if (type != null)
        {
            retValues.Add(type);
        }
        retValues.AddRange(VisualTreeFindAll<T>(child));
    }
    return retValues;
}
```

Use the name of a `UserControl` instance to call the `SetIsTabStop(bool flag)` method with `False`.

```
userControlName.SetIsTabStop(false);
```

**Update:**

Maybe you could try the following workaround.

Add the `KeyDown` event handler for the `UserControl` in your `Page`.

```
 private void UserControl_KeyDown (object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Tab)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            button1.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard);
        }
    }
```

You need to let the first control except the `UserControl` and all its child controls get the focus, then the key navigation will skip the child controls in the `UserControl` except the first child control in the `UserControl`.

Comment: Sorry. I reframed my question. Actually I've UserControl instead of StackPanel and that usercontrol has lot of child controls which will be added dynamically. So setting IsTabStop as false to each & every child controls is not possible in our application scenario. Is there any solution handle IsTabStop in parent user control level?

Comment: I update the answer. You could view if the update meets your requirements.

Comment: I already thought about this approach (updating all visual child controls). But our Parent UserControl has lot & lot child controls. So traversing entire Visual tree will impact performance heavily. Is there any other effective way to handle this?

Comment: I update the answer. You could view if the update meets your requirements.

Comment: Has your problem been solved? If it is not solved, please feel free to contact us.